# How is called this user control?

Tags: .net, user-controls

How is called this user control? It's better listbox.

[image: TaskManager]

**Thanks for your answers!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx). Essentially the same control Explorer used (in older Windows versions at least). It allows columns, sorting, various views (e.g. list, table, small icons, large icons).